# Using html2Canvas with HighCharts

Tags: html2canvas

I want to use html2canvas discussed at http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html to convert the html content to image. However I am not getting image of HighCharts properly. On IE10 It renders blank image and on Chrome it renders a part of it. Is it possible to use html2canvas for this purpose.

Comment: Highcharts uses svg to draw charts. 
You will need to use canvg library for drawing this svg to a temporary canvas and then remove that canvas once you take the screenshot using html2canvas.

Answer (score 11):

Highcharts uses svg to draw charts. You will need to use canvg library for drawing this svg to a temporary canvas and then remove that canvas once you take the screenshot using html2canvas.

Here is the link for canvg : https://code.google.com/p/canvg/downloads/list

Try this:

```
//find all svg elements in $container
//$container is the jQuery object of the div that you need to convert to image. This div may contain highcharts along with other child divs, etc
var svgElements= $container.find('svg');

//replace all svgs with a temp canvas
svgElements.each(function () {
    var canvas, xml;

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";
    //convert SVG into a XML string
    xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);

    // Removing the name space as IE throws an error
    xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');

    //draw the SVG onto a canvas
    canvg(canvas, xml);
    $(canvas).insertAfter(this);
    //hide the SVG element
    this.className = "tempHide";
    $(this).hide();
});

//...
//HERE GOES YOUR CODE FOR HTML2CANVAS SCREENSHOT
//...

//After your image is generated revert the temporary changes
$container.find('.screenShotTempCanvas').remove();
$container.find('.tempHide').show().removeClass('tempHide');
```

Comment: That didn't quite work with me, it's returning an empty canvas <canvas class="screenShotTempCanvas"></canvas>

Comment: @NaguibIhab Not sure whats going wrong there. Can you check if the $container is added to DOM before you take the screenshot? May be thats the issue.